# Invoke adapter from JSONStore window of MFP studio

Tags: javascript, android, sql, adapter, jsonstore

```
TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (2017-09-10T11:40:52.184Z/a8ef5f27690bd63d791070260187d949b6d420cf/sqlTest-impl.js#27)
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project MFPApp]nullorg.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (2017-09-10T11:40:52.184Z/a8ef5f27690bd63d791070260187d949b6d420cf/sqlTest-impl.js#27)
```

This happens when I am trying to create a JSONStore from the GUI. This is a SQL adapter.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on the blue MFP button, then choose MF JSONStore
2. choose application component name, click next
3. in the window enter the parameters for procedure, example - `{"ARGUMENTS":{"defNum":1,"defSize":1000},"HEADER":{}}`
4. It errors with the above error , line 27 in the impl file is 
   return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
5. this works fine when right clicking the adapter and invoking it, the parameters passed have been saved into a file and I am pasting the same options into the above window.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, 
I have found the solution. Hope it helps others.
We dont have to pass anything like key value pairs. Just enter the parameters separated by comma , for example for my problem :- 1,1000
This worked fine.